# How to have different toggle style for iOS and macOS

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to have toggle with native style for iOS (switch) and macOS (checkbox) in my universal app. This code does not work:

```
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
private let toggleStyle = CheckboxToggleStyle()
#else
private let toggleStyle = SwitchToggleStyle()
#endif
```

> 'CheckboxToggleStyle' is unavailable in iOS

Was thinking that macros should compile correct path for each target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CheckboxToggleStyle` is for macOS only... see below API declaration. macCatalyst is actually environment simulating iOS on macOS, but from API perspective it is iOS

> ```
> /// A `ToggleStyle` represented by a leading checkbox.
> @available(OSX 10.15, *)
> @available(iOS, unavailable)
> @available(tvOS, unavailable)
> @available(watchOS, unavailable)
> public struct CheckboxToggleStyle : ToggleStyle {
> ```

Comment: What is the recommended way to deal with something like this?